# Latex Error with bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors

I got a Latex error I can't seem to be able to fix... I wanted to change my bibliography style but ended up going back to my old one (simply by pressing Cmd + z) and now this message is showing up. Any suggestions?

```
l.21 \abx@aux@refcontext
                        {none/global//global/global}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Unfortunately, there's not enough information here for most of us to even guess how it happened.  We at least need to know what document class you're using, and also relevant packages and the bibliography style.  Best would be to provide a small compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem.  I know that may be difficult, but you can start by making a copy of your files in a new area, then removing anything that doesn't affect the result.  You may even find the problem yourself that way.

Comment: @Georgie Maybe try to delete all the auxiliary files and then compile again.